# Unable to Edit new layout in Sharepoint 2013 Designer (64 bit)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I created a new layout in Design Manager. I am admin on this site with full control.

In the SP designer 2013 I get:  Server error: This file may not be moved, deleted, renamed, or otherwise edited.

I originally built was working in my sandbox editing the display of web-parts, now I want to mimic that under the main layout area. How do I get around this error to edit document? I can edit its corresponding HTML document.

thank you,

Comment: Are you trying to update the page master or master layout or the actual html file that appears in the site? IIRC you should be creating then modifying a copy of an existing layout and deploy that layout via Site Settings?

Comment: I create the layout in designer manager. I base it upon the sites master page to get in the themes the site is using.   I publish it successfully, they appear in the folder page layouts in sharepoint designer, as I open them in advanced mode. when saving my changes (removing two webparts) I get the error stated above. I can select my new layout on a page I am editing. I have done this before in my sandbox, but not under the main site collection's page layouts.

Comment: I think issue has to deal with setup of central admin. On a two app servers, one was installed with Farm ID, and one was installed with an Active directory ID of a person who is not here anymore. I will attempt to uninstall and reinstall in the configuration wizard allowing the proper ID to be attached to the Central Administration console.